# Firebase Truncate of large node fails

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Database node of around 18 GB and I want to truncate it.
When I'm trying to import a single json object from the GUI on that node, I get the below mentioned error message:

```
There was a problem contacting the server. Try uploading your file again.
```

Getting the below error when trying to use the set command of Firebase Admin SDK using Firebase:

```
user_activities_sample = db.reference("userActivities")

user_activities_sample.set({"-LGdG7t06O4hx-6XhCABC":{"deviceId":"A97D675C-FD67-01B4-0000-000000000000","dow":"Thursday","email":"stewart@myoneevent.com"}})

firebase_admin.db.ApiCallError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: <my URL>
Reason: Data requested exceeds the maximum size that can be accessed with a single request.
```

Any help/support is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Tunicate is to clean. I would go to console.firebase.com and delete the top level node manually or do the below.

```
firebase.database().ref("userActivities").remove(); // this will tunicate everything under this branch
```

Comment: Is there a limit on using remove()? As per Firebase, truncating/deleting a node in Firebase is essentially a write operation with a limit of 256 MB.

Comment: You could always do a for each loop in the next level down so its not so resource heavy. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write